# Removing "Invalid or Missing Projection" window when adding an image with DotSpatial

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, dotspatial

I want to add an image to my win form app using DotSpatial. I use the code below (it works):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    map1.AddLayer(@"C:\image.png");
}
```

But I see "Invalid or Missing Projection" window to choose a projection. How can I set projection in code and remove the window above?

Answer (score 1):

See the DotSpatial Documentation or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122130/raster-data-loading-from-filepath-in-dotspatial to remove the "Invalid or Missing Projection" window.

I do this with a .tiff not .png. Add code below:

```
 IRaster r = Raster.Open(@"C:\image.tiff");
        DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo dest = default(DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo);
        dest = DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(4326); 
        r.Projection = dest;
        IMapRasterLayer myLayer = map1.Layers.Add(r);
```